# How to change apache service description in windows

Tags: apache, service

I'm running apache httpd server as a service in windows.
I want to change/hide the description for security reasons.
Refer the attached image: [Service snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFk2Q.png)
Can some one tell how to change/hide service description?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to look at doing this in Regedit,

```
Start Registry Editor (the Regedt32.exe tool).
Locate the following key in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer
\Parameters
NOTE: The above registry key is one path; it has been wrapped for readability. 

On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:
Value Name: hidden
Data Type: REG_BINARY
Value: 1
Quit Registry Editor.
NOTE: This setting can also be changed using the net config server /hidden:yes|no command.
```

Please see reference here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/265284

Comment: Thanks Steven  for the response. If I understand correctly the above registry configuration is for LanmanServer. I need to change the 'Apache - web server' service description.

Comment: The value can also be added as a parameter for the Apache service as well.  However, this really isn't a solution that meets the requirements.  The requirements were to change/hide the _description_.  This hides the entire _service_ from view.

It would appear that the only way to meet the need is to customize the code itself as identified here.
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=33922